# Determine which update panel caused postback?

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Suppose I have 3 update panels. How could I detect which update panel caused a partial postback from JavaScript.

Comment: do you mean that you call _dopostback() from javascript and on serverside you want to know that which updatepanel's _dopostback() you call???

Comment: Do you want to know this on the server side or client side (as suggested by "from JavaScript")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Hidden field**

assign value before calling _dopostback() in javascript and by this on server you can specify that which updatepanel is postback.

Answer (score 1):

I had a custom implementation of a web user control where I had a manager bound to the field, then I marked the input with an attribute so that I was able to find it easier
If you find a way to know which updatePanels you had, then you'd be able to do it too

This is a simple example, and the reasons for it to work that way would be a very long explanation, but I wanted to leave it here in case someone finds it useful

It may have some bug, I am rushed to leave, perhaps I'll get to test it later on today

If you put this inside an update panel you should see it working

```
   <span id="foo" customattr="foo_msg">click for foo_msg</span>
```

Finallu, what I did was something like this

```
<html>
 <head>
 //make sure this executes on load
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(myHandler);

function MyManager(message){
 this.message=message;
 this.notify=function(){alert(this.message);}
}

$(
 function(){
  $("[customattr=Y]").each(
   function(){
    this.objAttr=new MyManager($(this).attr("customattr"));
    $.data(document.body,this.id,objAttr);
    $(this).click(
     function(){
      this.objAttr.notify();
     }
    )
   }
 }
);

function myHandler(a,b){
 $("[customattr]").each(
  function(){
   if(!this.objAttr){
    //smells like postback regenerated this field

    //let's get it back
    this.objAttr=$.data(document.body,this.id);

   }
  }
 );
}
 </head>
 <body>
   <span id="foo" customattr="foo_msg">click for foo_msg</span>
   <span id="bar" customattr="bar_msg">click for bar_msg</span>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: I assume that 'in javascript' means... after the postback returned